# Forking Swap from bsc on goerli, max input of native token 0

Tags: ether, decentralized-exchange, swaps, wrapped-tokens

I'm trying to fork cheeseswap from bsc onto goerli. I've also tried to fork another swap from another network onto goerli and have the same issue.  I Change all the chainid numbers,  rpcs, factory,  router,  pairkey hash, and wrapped native token address.

My ETH shows up when i go to swap as the amount available,  but if I click max input.. it puts 0 rather than the amount.  Also if I go to do a swap with the native token it fails. It "says this is probably an issue with one of the tokens your swapping".

Token to token works fine.

Anything involving native token does not.

There is obviously some variable related to the native token I'm forgetting to adjust.. does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Goerli, Sepolia are testnetwork. The tokens there are worth nothing.

If you try bridging from BSC probably it is trying to prevent you from loosing your tokens.

You shouldn't bridge assets between production and test networks.